# How to turn off Scala auto-completion of function with Unit return type in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin has a feature for automatically adding `:Unit` to the end of unit-returning functions. So, for example, if I'm writing a side-effecting function `foo`:

```
def foo() {}
```

when I hit `Enter` while the cursor is between the braces, I'll get the following:

```
def foo():Unit = {

}
```

I, personally, prefer the following instead:

```
def foo() {

}
```

So, how do I turn this feature off?

Comment: Be aware that this syntax will be deprecated and then removed in future Scala versions. So even if you prefer the old 'procedure syntax', it might not be wise to use it across your code base. The newest IntelliJ IDEA Scala Plugin "folds" (hides) the `: Unit =`, so optically it looks similar to the procedure syntax.

Comment: Yes, it will. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7605

Comment: hmm i wasn't aware of this deprecation effort, nor do I agree with it. seems strongly skewed towards "people learning Scala"... hopefully there'll be a way to turn off the deprecation nagging for this specific feature - perhaps similar to postfixOps

Comment: the downvotes are undeserved, see the official stackoveflow FAQ:
When should I vote down?
Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Comment: Incidentally, does anyone know how to _prevent_ Intellij from hiding `: Unit =`? I didn't find anything in the Editor > Code Folding preferences...

Comment: are you using the latest version of the Scala plugin? i'm on 0.41.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
tldr;
Preferences > Code Style > Scala > Other > Uncheck: Enforce procedure syntax [blah blah blah]
```

1. Open IntelliJ `Preferences` dialog
2. In the right panel expand `Code Style`
3. Select `Scala`
4. Click on tab titled `Other`
5. Uncheck `Enforce procedure syntax for methods with Unit return type`