# How to disable folding of `: Unit =` in scala procedures in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

In recent versions of Intellij IDEA, when writing a scala method which returns `Unit`(a.k.a. a procedure), IDEA will fold the `: Unit =` part, so that it displays like the so-called "procedure syntax". Here's what it looks like :

```
def myMethod(): Unit = {
  // do something
}
```

gets folded by default to :

```
def myMethod()  {
  // do something
}
```

I understand the point, since the procedure syntax is slated for deprecation but some people still like it, I guess it's a good compromise for them. However, for those of us who don't like the procedure syntax, I wasn't able to find a setting to disable that code folding by default. Preferences > Editor > Code folding does show some scala-specific settings for which code foldings should be collapsed by default, but the only one I have checked is "Shell comments (scala script)".

Does someone know how to disable this feature? Or is it currently impossible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off Scala auto-completion of function with Unit return type in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468047/how-to-turn-off-scala-auto-completion-of-function-with-unit-return-type-in-intel)

Comment: No duplicate there - my question is about the way code is displayed (no impact on the actual source code written to the file), the question you link to is about auto-complete of the actual code. Edit: didn't remember asking about display issues in the comments - but still a different question IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's in Preferences -> code style -> Scala, then on the right there are two hidden tabs, go on other and there should be a check with *Enforce procedural syntax for methods with Unit return type*

[image]

For Intellij 14 the path is slightly different:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I didn't think to look in "Code Style": I would have thought it was only for settings which modify the actual source code when auto-formatting, rather than just changing how it's displayed like in this case.

Comment: And usually it's like that (PHP, JS, SQL and many others) the Scala and Java plugin seems to be an exception for many cases.